# Error when Opening Whatsapp Web and configuring Options()

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

Hi I am trying to access the webwhatsapp and I am trying to configure Google chrome not an automated machine. I am trying to get the HTML of the page after that but I am receiving an error message which I am unable to figure out the solution for, I have found similar answers but none of them fixed the issue and the same error remained.

Here is the error I keep receiving:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: userAutomationExtension
```

Here is the code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#Trial
# options = webdriver.Options()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("userAutomationExtension",False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/User1/Downloads/chromedriver.exe",options=options)

url="https://web.whatsapp.com/"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(20)
r = requests.get(url, timeout=30)

soup     = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

chat_list = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Chat list'})
print(chat_list)
```

**My Question**

Why I am receiving this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `options.add_experimental_option("userAutomationExtension",False)` , it should be

```
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```